# Does the ServiceBusProcessor completes messages implicitly?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

For my code below, the `ServiceBusProcessor` completes messages even if the 'CompleteMessageAsync' is not called. I tried specifying `ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock`  to no avail too.

How do I enable explicit completion of messages?

```
static ServiceBusProcessor processor;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   processor= client.CreateProcessor("myTopic", "mySubs", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions() );
   processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
   processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
   processor.StartProcessingAsync();
}

static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
   string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
   //No explicit 'CompleteMessageAsync' here
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out by adding the processor option`AutoCompleteMessages=false`

Code should look like this:

`processor= client.CreateProcessor("myTopic", "mySubs", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions() { AutoCompleteMessages=false});`